# System.InvalidOperationException: when accessing DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, asp.net-core-1.1

I'm getting an error when running my .Net Core application.  I get to accessing the DbContext and this pops up

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.'

I've tried fixing it but it still comes up.

**DbContext.cs**

```
public class PartsDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Tower> Towers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Motherboard> Motherboards { get; set; }

    public PartsDbContext(DbContextOptions<PartsDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

**Controller.cs**

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private readonly PartsDbContext _context;

    public AdminController(PartsDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        if (User.Identity.Name == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Register", "Account");
        }
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Towers()
    {
        var model = _context.Towers.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }

    public IActionResult Motherboards()
    {
        var model = _context.Motherboards.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

The error shows up on this line in Towers()

> ```
> var model = _context.Towers.ToList();
> ```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
      options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddDbContext<PartsDbContext>();

    services.AddMvc();

    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
}
```

Any help would be nice.  I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I believe I've done all the things that the error suggests.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you actually got a `DefaultConnection` configured in your `App.config`?

Comment: there is no App.config.  I'm using ASP.Net Core 1.1 and I don't believe that uses App.config

Comment: Oh sorry, `appsettings.json`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings#aspnet-core

Comment: ah yes it says this
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-PrecisionCustomPC-b14db89e-86ad-4855-a17f-ac64a04339aa;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current `Startup.cs` file has configured the DB provider for one DB (`ApplicationDBContext`) but not the one you are using (`PartsDbContext`).

So, add these lines:

```
services.AddDbContext<PartsDbContext>(options =>  
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
)
```

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#using-dbcontext-with-dependency-injection

Comment: I thought that this was suppose to configure the DB provider to be entity-framework:

    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddDbContext<PartsDbContext>();

Comment: @JoeHigley, Entity Framework is an ORM, not the db provider. The DB provider is SQL, mySql, Oracle, etc.

Comment: This has fixed the posted issue.  However I now have a problem where it doesn't seem that Entity Framework is creating any Tables.  I get an error on the same line as before but with this message instead: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'Towers'.'

Comment: @JoeHigley I suggest you create a new question for that :)

Comment: I have done so here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43767933/entity-framework-system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-invalid-object-name).  Feel free to answer it there if you know what's up.