# Entity Framework core navigation property between two contexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-framework-core

There are similar questions with this issue, but not for EF Core. Not a duplicate of [Entity Framework Core Using multiple DbContexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43767933/entity-framework-core-using-multiple-dbcontexts) . That one is related to not being able to access the database at all from the second context, and the two contexts use different databases. This question is about a single database and the issue is related to migrations

---

I have two EF core db contexts using the same SQL Server database.

In the first context I have many entities, one of them is User.

In the second one there is a single entity called UserExt which has a navigational property to User

```
public class UserExt
{
    [Key]
    public long UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

The issue is that when creating the migration for UserExt using 'add-migration', all entities from the first context are also included.

Tried providing the context, but same result

```
add-migration --context SecondContext
```

With EF 6 it was possible to solve this using ContextKey (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrationsconfiguration.contextkey(v=vs.113).aspx) but has not been ported to EF Core

Is there a way to make this work so that the migrations in the second context would contain only its entities ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Core Using multiple DbContexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43767933/entity-framework-core-using-multiple-dbcontexts)

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh that question is related to not being able to access the database at all from the second context, and the two contexts use different databases. this ticket is about a single database and the issue is related to migrations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using database context inheritance. This way I can have separate migrations.

```cs
public class SecondDbContext : FirstDbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<UserExt> ExtendedUsers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
       optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("connectionString", options => 
            options
               .MigrationsAssembly("SecondDbContextAssemblyName")
               .MigrationsHistoryTable("__SecondEFMigrationsHistory") // separate table to store migration history to avoid conflicts
       );
    } 
}
```

Because `SecondDbContext` is inherited from `FirstDbContext`, every entity change made in the base context will be inherited. Which means that when a new migration is added to the second context, it will try to apply the changes again from the first context again. Workaround is to:

- Add a new migration (for example `Add-Migration Inherit_FirstDbContext`)
- Delete everything from the migration's `Up` and `Down` methods
- Apply the empty migration in the database. (`Update-Database`)

This ensures that the Entity Framework snapshot will contain the changes, without actually having to re-apply them in the database.