# Blazor App: change database connection after login

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor

We have a Blazor Server-Aapp. The app uses ef core. After authorization / login i  want to change the database connection for the current session. I have some ideas but does anybody knows the best aproach  for this? We do not use a repository. The context is just directly injected where it is needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I connect to multiple databases from a Blazor .NET Core project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62100637/how-can-i-connect-to-multiple-databases-from-a-blazor-net-core-project)

Comment: Is it just for 2 databases or full multi-tennant?

Comment: its for multi-tennant - sorry that describes exact what i want.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to use different databases for login and other data entities. In that case, why not create different `DbContext` one for auth purpose and other for data entities?

One DbContext can have connection string for auth database and the other for your business data. For example:

Auth data context:

```
services.AddDbContext<AuthContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AuthConnection")));
```

Business data context:

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataConnection")));
```

Comment: The op clearly says: After authorization / login i want to change the database connection for the current session. Injection occurs before this.